# O que é o método Accessor e Mutating no Swift ?? Para o que serve?

Tags: ios, swift

Quando nós criamos uma struct em Swift, podemos utilizar o método
Mutating e Accessor.

Qual é o propósito ? O que ele soluciona e para que funciona.

Answer (score 1):

*Mutating* indica que o método modifica o estado interno da *Struct*.
Em Swift, há uma importante diferença entre *Value Types* e *Reference Types*.
*Enum* e *Struct* são *Value Types*. *Class* é *Reference Type*.
Por padrão, é um erro de programação declarar um método que modifica o estado de um Value Type.

```
struct MyStruct {
    var value = 0

    func changeValue() {
        value = 10 //Erro: Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
    }
}
```

Declarando o método com o modificador *mutating*, é possível modificar o estado do objeto:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var value = 0

    mutating func changeValue() {
        value = 10 // OK
    }
}
```

É possível até mesmo mudar a valor de self:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var value = 0

    mutating func changeValue() {
        self = MyStruct(value: 32)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ficou claro o uso do `mutating` mas quando o usuário pergunta *O que é o método Accessor e Mutating no Swift* acredito eu, posso estar equivocado e considero contra-argumento, que quando ele diz *método Accessor* queira saber além de como funciona o `mutating`  também queira saber como funciona o `setter` em propriedades computadas e propriedades encapsuladas e suas diferenças.